# flutter ecommerce products not retrieving

Tags: e-commerce, nullable, riverpod

I keep getting error of "null check applied to a null value" at runtime. When I delete the ! symbol, dart recommends adding this or ? back to remove code error during dev. I am suspecting the error is coming from my feedsScreen or product model but not sure as there's no other stack trace shown. See snippets of the usual suspect screens.

I have come to the end of my wits and will appreciate all insights I can get. Thanks in advance

[image: FeedsScreen]

[image: FeedsProduct]

[image: Product_Controller for StateNotifier actions]

[image: Product model]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Since `products` is already known, `AsyncValue` passed to the super constructor should be `AsyncValue.data(products)`

Like so:

```
ProductNotifier(this._read): super(AsyncValue.data(products));
```